# Android app gives up connecting faster if I rotate the phone while it's loading

Tags: bug, android-app

When I open the official Stack Exchange app for Android (cold open, it hasn't been running in the background) with a janky Internet connection, it takes about ten seconds before giving up and presenting me with a failure message. However, if I open it (after force-closing the previous instance) and then rotate my phone, it gives up immediately.

I have version 1.0.75 running on Android 4.4.3. My phone is an HTC Desire 612, model number HTC331ZLVW.

(I'm  not sure if this is actually a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but it's kind of weird, and I thought people might want to know about it.)

Comment: I couldn't repro it on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, app v1.0.82 (beta). Is this still happening on your case?